# Is there a way to keep the command line open to see the results of my program?

Tags: python

I have coded a temperature converter from Celsius to Fahrenheit. When I run the program from my desktop, it asks for my input then quickly closes when I pass an integer to it. Is there a way to keep it open to view the results?

```
user_input_celsius = input('Enter temp in Celsius ')

user_input_celsius = int(user_input_celsius)




celsius_values = []

celsius_values = celsius_values + [user_input_celsius]

fahrenheit_values = []



for celsius in celsius_values:

     fahrenheit = celsius * 1.8 + 32

     fahrenheit_values = fahrenheit_values + [fahrenheit]

print(fahrenheit_values, end ='')
```

Comment: welcome to SO, you should check if an answer exists before creating a new question!

Answer (score 0):

You have some options:

Run the program from an already-open terminal. Open a command prompt and type:

```
python myscript.py
```

Add code to wait at the end of your script:

```
input()
```

Comment: Yes thank you, that has solved the problem :)

Comment: @Hydra17 Mark my response please ^^

Comment: I did but because my rep < 15 it doesn't show publicy

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the user to input any value before closing
This way the program will not close until you type something

```
# program.py

user_input_celsius = input('Enter temp in Celsius ')    
user_input_celsius = int(user_input_celsius)
celsius_values = []    
celsius_values = celsius_values + [user_input_celsius]    
fahrenheit_values = []
for celsius in celsius_values:
         fahrenheit = celsius * 1.8 + 32    
     fahrenheit_values = fahrenheit_values + [fahrenheit]    
print(fahrenheit_values, end ='')

input("Press enter to exit")
exit()
```